# Smart way to solve (complex) polynomial equation

Tags: polynomials, roots

Solve for all solutions: $z^4+z^3-3z^2-17z-30=0, z \in \mathbb{C} $, Premise: $-1+2i$ is a solution

I would factor $-1+2i$ out, guess another root, which can be factored out again, to get an polynomial of deg 2.

Is there another (smarter) way to get those solutions ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you dont *guess* another root. Since $-1+2i$ is a root and since the coefficients are real, then you *know* that $-1-2i$ is another root.

Comment: Ah, because if $p(x_0) = a_nx_0^n + ... + a_0 = 0$, then $p(\bar x_0) = a_n \bar x_0^n + ... +a_0 = conjugate(a_nx_0^n + ... + a_0) = conjugate(0) = 0$

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: But then I need to factor these 2 solutions out to get the rest right ?

Comment: I would divide your polynomial by $(x+1-2i)(x+1+2i)=x^2+2x+5$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$-1-2i$$ is also a solution of your equation.